# hover after transition with border-radius not smooth

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a css transition who is perfectly working on hover but if we un-hover it at the end of the animation, at the left side of the button there is a piece of the `:after` who overflows the button. It looks like the animation is coming back to a square form without `border-radius`

Fiddle of my button: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xonv9kgr/)

Comment: i never thought overflow hidden would work on a border radius, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `overflow: hidden;` in `.loginBut`